# remove_action not working with procedural function

Tags: actions

I have a purchased theme that procedurally loads an action like this:

```
function func() {
    echo "head content";
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'func', 5 );
```

Following the [remove action codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action) I tried the following:

```
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'func', 5 );
```

Which did not work so I figured it was a priority issue so I adjusted both higher and lower neither worked.  Then I tried wrapping the function in another function like:

```
function testfunc() {
    if (remove_action( 'wp_head', 'func', 5 )) {
        echo "removed action";
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'testfunc', 1000 );
```

Again playing with the priority.  The whole time `remove_action` is returning true but not removing the action.  Then I tried adding the wrapping function in the `init` action and it worked.  Great! Unfortunately I have no idea why.  Somewhat more perplexing is the wrapping function is required.  Lastly, the codex specifically states:

> It is also worth noting that you may need to prioritise the removal of the action to a hook that occurs **after the action is added**. You cannot successfully remove the action before it has been added.

And according to [this codex entry](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) both `init` and `get_header` (which worked) are before the `wp_head` action the function was hooked into.  Can someone demystify this for me?

Edit: To answer @sumit's question the `add_action` happens via an include in the main themes functions.php (it includes library/core.php).  The `remove_action` is in the functions.php of the child theme.

Comment: @toscho Why is wordpress.org not applicable?

Comment: Because your question is not about that site.

Comment: Would you mind to explain that where did you add `add_action` and `remove_action` ?

Comment: @toscho I figured that was to distinguish between wordpress.com and the OSS version.  Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: For child themes and plugins (*which loads before the parent theme*), the action needs to be removed before it is added by the parent theme. If you need to remove core actions, you can remove it by using the same hook with the same priority.

Comment: @PieterGoosen Wow good to know (on load order).  The wrapping function is necessary to get earlier priority and still have the `remove_action` indicate the action to remove is part of the `wp_head` action?  Do you have a reference that says the action needs to be removed _before_ when using a child theme?  Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue here is that the child theme functions.php is loaded before the parent theme functions.php. Therefore, the ordering of the add/remove actions would be something like so:

```
//* From the child theme
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'func', 5 );
//* From the parent theme
add_action( 'wp_head', 'func', 5 );
```

The callback to `func` on the `wp_head` hook is removed before it's added. Therefore, it will appear that the child theme removing the action doesn't work. In reality, the `remove_action()` function is attempting to remove the `func` callback from the `wp_head` hook, but it hasn't been added yet.

The solution is to hook into WordPress anytime after the parent theme functions.php loads and then remove the action.

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpse_222809_after_setup_theme' );
function wpse_222809_after_setup_theme() {
  remove_action( 'wp_head', 'func', 5 );
}
```

This works because the `after_setup_theme` hook fires after the parent theme functions.php, so the ordering of the add/remove actions would thus be:

```
//* From the child theme
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpse_222809_after_setup_theme' );
//* From the parent theme
add_action( 'wp_head', 'func', 5 );
//* From the wpse_222809_after_setup_theme function hooked to after_setup_theme 
//*( hook added in child theme )
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'func', 5 );
```

This would also work with replacing `after_setup_theme` with `init`, as you figured out, because the `init` hook is fired after the parent theme functions.php and before `wp_head`.